# Serve a directory in ec2

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have an ec2 instance running ubuntu that I can ssh in to upload/download files. However, ssh is often blocked on public wifis (library, cafes,etc). Is there a way to serve the contents of a directory over http to download files?

I tried using `python -m SimpleHttpServer`, but i cant seem to access it using: public-ip:port

Answer (score 0):

Is this a connectivity issue? (e.g., can you not access public-up:port at all) or more regarding serving files using a tool such as SimpleHttpServer?  You could always just switch the port you're running SSH on, no?